# Wordpress 3.1.2 Network Enabled non-www to www

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, multisite

OK so i am drawing a blank. I have setup a WordPress 3.1.2 Network site and want the main site to appear with www.mydomain.com not mydomain.com and i can get that to work but the back-end on the network admin breaks when i go to add a site it gives me the error "Are you sure you want to do this".

When i disable the redirect of non-www to www it works fine. I have setup the wp_options table with site home and url of www.mydomain.com so i do not get this at all. I had it working in 3.0 but now 3.1 not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you trying to do the force redirect? I think the best place for this may be in a `.htaccess` file. Something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your_domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your_domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I have tried that and the network admin gets broken and if i redirect to www i need to tell wordpress that the main url is now www.mydomain.com or it will think that www is a sub-site

Comment: I'm assuming you've set your General Settings -> Site address and WordPress address to http://www.example.com?

Comment: i have tried it both way's with my settings at www.mydomain.com and the rewritecode in .htaccess and domains at mydomain.com and the rewritecode in .htaccess

Comment: humm... I just had to change BOTH the url settings in my general settings and it worked like a charm. Try removing (or renaming/backup) your .htaccess file. Change your general URL settings and then regenerate permalinks.